# SSRS Reports on WUXGA Displays

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2012

We use WUXGA displays (1920 x 1200), and have lots of SSRS reports. Since these reports need to be printed once in a while the layout is adjusted to A4. However when the users look at the reports on the display around 40% of the screen is blank. Absolut waste of screen space. How can I adjust SSRS to use the full screen size for reports ?

Comment: Just change the report 'interactive size' to one that looks best for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the web interface to run and view the reports there is an option to set the zoom level by appending **&rc:Zoom=Page Width** or whatever percentage you want.

Also it can be configured in the SSRS configuration file see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155866.aspx) for details.

Comment: This is pretty good, but is there any way to do this so that the report doesn't appear stretched when zoomed? (This might be a limitation of SSRS.)

Comment: Can you try setting the Report property ConsumeContainerWhitespace to true and see if that helps?

Comment: That didn't seem to help. I think that setting has something to do with the canvas in the designer.

Comment: Can you try exporting it in PDF, and opening it in the same zoom level and see if it renders the same?

Comment: I suppose I should mention that the entirety of *my* report is a graph, so there may be no way to fix that. I'll try what you suggest anyway just to see what happens.

Comment: Well that's interesting. The PDF appears to be vectorized and it displays great even when zoomed in! I wonder why the web interface doesn't do that. Edit: I'm using SSRS 2008 R2, though.

Comment: Could be the graph element. SSRS is far from perfect. but if you print the report or deliver it to users than have it auto-generated and send it over to users exported in PDF. I have no other idea what to suggest.

Comment: My particular report is only for internal use (mainly just me at this point); I was just curious about a general solution for this issue because it would be nice to have the report fill the screen without adjusting the size of the canvas. Thanks for your help, though, this was actually a pretty informative experiment.

Comment: You're welcome. I know how it can be a pain to get decent SSRS information.